# D3: Is there a way to get maximum values between x-axis ticks?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It's quite straight-forward to get them (eg. looping through data) if ticks are always every week (d3.time.weeks). I would like to know is there a generic solution, if tick intervals (d3.time.months, d3.time.weeks, etc) are different based on period length of data.

In the example below the value 6 is the maximum value of the week (January 1 -  January 7).

[image]

Comment: i feel the question is not clear...this part _"display all maximum values below the graph. No need to display them in the graph."_

Comment: I removed that part. It's not relevant. I just need to find the values.